# Connecting PID Controller to SSR

Tags: solid-state-relay, pid-controller

I am trying to connect together

1. PID Controller ([ALTEC PC410](http://www.ebay.com/itm/121409284851), `Output Relay (NO, max. 250VAC, 3A)`)
2. K-type thermocouple
3. SSR ([uxcell SSR-25 DA 25A 3-32V DC / 24-380V AC Solid State Relay + Heat Sink](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0087ZTN08))

**Question** Do I connect

1. SSR Input Pins `3` and `4` to the PC410 `OUT1` pins `4` and `5`?
2. 110VAC `L` to PC410 pin `1` and SSR Output pin `1`
3. 110VAC 'N' to PC410 pin `2` and one end of Load
4. SSR Output pin `2` to the other end of Load

**Proposed Wiring Diagram**

*On the SSR, top 2 pins are labelled `LOAD`, bottom 2 pins `INPUT`*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have it right. Observe polarity on the DC input to the SSR. **Add appropriate fuses and an overtemperature cutout for safety**.

Edit: Re your proposed wiring diagram edit, it's better to switch the hot rather than the neutral, as in your verbal description. You have the wrong pins on the controller as well (should be 4&5 like your verbal description).

Always fuse the HOT line, not the neutral.

Comment: Thanks I made the changes to my wiring diagram in the OP. Does it look better now? Where on the Hot line should I place the fuse?

Comment: Looks good. Fuse goes in series with the hot from the line cord (so both the SSR and the controller are fused).

Comment: The PID output is speced `Output: relay, normally open contact (max.250VAC, 3A)`. Is this suitable to trigger the SSR whose input accepts `25A 3-32V DC`?

Comment: I believe it brings the relay drive voltage out on pins 4 and 5 "Logic level , 20V/20mA, can trigger high- SSR". Of course the relay is a dry contact and cannot trigger an SSR without an external power supply.

Comment: There are 3 output options `Relay`, `Analog` and `Logic`. http://www.china-altec.com/english/products/temperature/pc900/PC900.htm

Comment: Oh so to clarify, I need to get the version with `L` output `Logic, (20 V/20 mA),drive solid state relay(SSR)`?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: If I have the `Relay` output version, does it mean I can connect the heating element directly to the output pins of the PID controller and forgo using the SSR? The heating elements are rated for 120VAC and draws lesser than 3A.

Comment: Yes, you can but the relay will wear out after some months or more of continuous use. Figure 100,000 +/-50% operations.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like it's better for me to get the `Logic` output version of the PID controller and use an external SSR.

Comment: Or use an external  power supply such as an old wall wart with 5-20VDC out and wire it in series with the relay to power the SSR